# How connect Spyder to mysql on Winx64 and Fedora?

Tags: python, pyqt4, spyder

Im trying to use Spyder with pyodbc to connect mysql using a PyQT4 gui framework. 
I have pyodbc in Spyder figure out.

How do I use PyQt4 to get info into gui's?  I'm looking to use gui on Fedora and winx64.

Edit: I figured out the fedora driver. Can anyone help me with QMYSQL driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/sql-driver.html#how-to-build-the-mysql-driver-for-mingw-users

Maybe that will help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using PyQt's built-in MySQL support? This could make it a bit easier to display DB info, depending on what you want the interface to look like.

Comment: I need help building Mysql driver.

Comment: can you help create the QmySql driver? I have never compiled anything. Using xp64 and fedora.